# How to wrap "with-usable" object into class?

Tags: python, encapsulation, with-statement

Suppose we have an object, which is intended to be used with `with`:

```
with somefunction() as f:
   ...
   f.somemethod()
```

Now I want to use it within class, to make object available full lifetime of class instance.

In constructor I would write

```
class MyClass:
   def __init__(self):
      self.f = somefunction().__enter__()
```

Where should I call `__exit__()` then?

Comment: Why not make `MyClass` a context manager?

Comment: You misunderstand the usage of `with`, it's only meant as a convenience, to automatically handle expensive setup and teardown you can't entrust to the user.

Comment: You can add a `__del__` method to your class, but I'd drastically rethink the model instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, I thought about it. What are advantages and disadvantages?

Comment: `__del__` is not guaranteed to be called.

Answer (score 0):

If `somefunction` is an object, first we could name it `someobject` and do something like:

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self, someobject):
        self._someobject = someobject


    def dothing(self):
        with self._someobject() as so:
            so.somemethod()


myinstance = MyClass(someobject)
myinstance.dothing()
```